# Почему в транскрипции слова «аллея» нет знака «:»?

Tags: фонетика

При фонетическом разборе слова ***аллея*** на других сайтах не ставится после ***л*** знак «:», обозначающий долгое произношение, хотя в других словах с удвоенными согласными чаще всего его ставим. Почему тогда в этом слове его нет?

Answer (score 3):

Из словаря:

[**АЛЛЕЯ**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%8F&all=x), -и; ***ж.*** [франц. allée].

Это слово — иноязычного происхождения, двойное «л» в русском его написании сохранилось от языка-источника.

В русском же языке имеется тенденция к упрощению двойных согласных, которые находятся не на стыках морфем. Какими-либо правилами фонетического или грамматического характера произношение таких иноязычных (в основном) слов не регулируется — какие-то из них могут произноситься с двойным (длинным) согласным ( в основном, в словах, связанных с религиозными понятиями — к примеру, *а[**лл**]ах*), другие — с согласным нормальной длительности, как если бы вместо двух одинаковых согласных в написании слова присутствовала только одна согласная. В некоторых случаях имеет место двоякое произношение — с двойным согласным и без него (так, к примеру, правильно и *а[**бб**]ат*, и *а[**б**]ат*).

В словах, написанных с двойным «л», **обычно** произносится одно «л» не только в слове ***аллея***, но и в этих словах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Фото сделано с «Большого орфоэпического словаря русского языка» под ред. Л.Л. Касаткина.)

Answer (score 0):

**[Произношение двойных согласных.](https://studopedia.net/10_6525_proiznoshenie-dvoynih-soglasnih.html)**

Нет **точных правил** произношения двойных согласных в заимствованных словах: в одних случаях произносится двойной согласный, а в других согласный с нормальной длительностью: группа, касса.

Обычно произношение двойного согласного сохраняется в ряде общеупотребительных слов в положении непосредственно **после ударного гласного:** группа, сумма, касса, ванна, тонна.

Р. И. Аванесов считает, что **длительность произношения двойного согласного не на стыке морфем зависит от того, встречается ли данный согласный на стыке морфем.** Например, **двойной р** на стыке морфем в русском языке отсутствует, поэтому он никогда не произносится как двойной: те[р]аса, су[р]огат.

То же самое можно сказать **о звуке л.**

Кроме того, произношение долгого согласного или согласного обычной длительности зависит от положения двойного согласного в зависимости **от ударения**: - долгий согласный произносится после ударения: группа, ванна, касса, масса; - **согласный обычной длительности произносится перед ударением и в конце слова:** кла[с], конгре[с], ба[с]ейн, **а[л]ея.**

Comment: «_Например, двойной **р** на стыке морфем в русском языке отсутствует, поэтому он **никогда** не произносится как двойной_» === Как выяснилось при более детальном изучении произношения слов с двойным «р», всё же некоторые из таких слов **могут** произноситься с долгим (двойным) _**р**_: _**дурра, мирра, сурра, сьерра…**_

Comment: А кто детально изучал? В словаре нашли? Возможно, это спорный вопрос, но главное – произношение во многом зависит от  ударного слога,  в частности в слове "аллЕя" произносится Л.  При разборе на это нужно ориентироваться.

Comment: «_А кто детально изучал? В словаре нашли?_» === Да, в словаре.

Comment: Там для различения: мира и мирра.

Comment: «_Там для различения: мира и мирра._» ===  «Там» — это где? Я «это» нашёл в «Большом орфоэпическом словаре», на который ссылался в своём ответе.

Comment: Где увидели.  Это мое предположение, если что.